# Angular app login on Windows 10 shows Status (failed) (works if using Mac)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows

[image]

I have a problem developing an Angular app on Windows 10. It works fine on Mac.
The product consists of:

- a) marksale-nodejs-server (REST-API)
- b) marksale-frontend (Angular)

b) shows a login-form gets data from an c) marksale.de account

the network-tab of the Chrome browser gives me the following feedback:
chrome web browser shows me (CTRL + SHIFT + i) in
    Network> click login> click 
**Headers**:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/login
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application / json, text / plain, * / *
Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = UTF-8
Origin: http: // localhost: 4200
Referer: http: // localhost: 4200 / login
User-Agent: Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 66.0.3359.181 Safari / 537.36
email: sl ... @ gmail.com
password: .....
```

**Response**:

Network> click login> click Response:
 
Response is empty. it shows nothing.

*What could i do?*

this i did before:

```
...\npm install -g @angular/cli
...\marksale-nodejs-server>npm --v
6.1.0
is this correct? is not already a version 10 out there?

...\marksale-nodejs-server>npm install pm2 -g
...\marksale-nodejs-server>pm2 update
...\marksale-nodejs-server>pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

it shows:
marksale_client_demo │ fork │ online │ 12 │ 0%  │ 18.6 MB

...\marksale-frontend>npm start

and started 
http://localhost:4200/login
this shows the login-form
```

Comment: Have you tried tried running `npm start` instead of `pm2`? Could be `pm2` couldn't map paths. Also, can you post your `RoutingModule`?

Comment: Also, why's the request going to port `3000`? `Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/login`

Comment: @PraveenP if i us pm start ecosystem.config.js i got errors. for e.g. ERR! code ELIFECYCLE . if i use pm2 i got now errors.

Comment: It could be due to your `package.json` not being configured properly. In that case, can you run `ng serve --proxy-config ecosystem.config.js` at where the `ecosystem.config.js` file is?

Comment: marksale-nodejs-server\clients.json use "port": 3000 and the client runs on 4200, should send to 3000.

Comment: >ng serve --proxy-config ecosystem.config.js
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. i only have this file in the marksale-frontend

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing this project is design to run with `pm2`. Are you able to put debug using Chrome Inspection tool? Or console log the HTTP response at the service level to see what response or error it returns?

Comment: it sends no errors. The response remains empty.

Comment: Can you use CURL of Postman to call the service directly and see if it's responding as expected?

Comment: 1. \marksale-nodejs-server>CURL http://localhost:4200
<!doctype html><script src="https://use.typekit.net ... 
2. curl: Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

Comment: Ok, so good news your code is fine. It's the Windows being Windows blocking the port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Windows allow apps to use port 3000.

1. Navigate to Control Panel, System and Security and Windows Firewall.
2. Select Advanced settings and highlight Inbound Rules in the left
   pane.
3. Right-click Inbound Rules and select New Rule.
4. Add the port you need to open and click Next.
5. Add the protocol (TCP or UDP) and the port number into the next
   window and click Next.
6. Select Allow the connection in the next window and hit Next.
7. Select the network type as you see fit and click Next.
8. Name the rule something meaningful and click Finish.

You'll need to perform the same process with outbound (step 3) as well.

Source: https://www.tomshardware.co.uk/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,news-57838.html

Comment: no response. i choosed TCP and created two rules. first inbound then outbound

Comment: Hmm, what's the backend service? I.E. Java REST API? or NodeJS?